# How to append mapped items into a new array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have some `object`s that I got from `map()` an `API` `URL` then `fetch()` those `URL`s and got these objects as the `return` (see the picture).

So I want to put all of these `object`s into a new `array` so I can use the `array` to create a `react component` that will use the information from there.

Could anyone help me out to figure it out to give me some hint on how to solve this problem? thanks before.

[image: return object]

```
const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=5";

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const fetchUrl = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const respData = await resp.json();
    const data = respData.results;
    data.map((pokemon) => {
      fetchPokemon(pokemon);
    });
  };

  const fetchPokemon = (pokemon) => {
    let url = pokemon.url;
    fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((pokemonData) => {
        finalData(pokemonData);
      });
  };

  const finalData = (pokemonData) => {
    console.log(pokemonData, "data");
  };
};
```

Comment: Without the source code, it's not clear what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your desired array of object by returning your data in map function and then push it into array.

```
const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=5";

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const fetchUrl = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const respData = await resp.json();
    const data = respData.results;
    const newArray = [];
    data.map((pokemon) => {
      newArray.push(fetchPokemon(pokemon));
    });
  };

  const fetchPokemon = async (pokemon) => {
    let url = pokemon.url;
    let data = {}
    return fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((pokemonData) => {
        return pokemonData;
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, how can I use ```const newArray = [];``` on a local scope? Even when I move it to global is only return ```[]``` value